# jquery not working in nw.js (node webkit)

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js, nwjs

I am switching my desktop app from electron to nw.js because of source code security features.

I am requiring the module jquery-confirm in my nodejs file, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: jquery-confirm requires jQuery
```

I fix this error by:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
var jconfirm = require('jquery-confirm');
```

and importing the js file in index.html like this:

```
<script>require('./bot.js')</script>
```

Becuase I get the same jquery error if I require the js file like:

```
<script src="bot.js"></script>
```

When I fix the error like above and I launch the app with nw.js, it immediately crashes giving this error:

```
TypeError: $(...).button is not a function
```

First question:
I am assuming there is something wrong with jquery. When I import it in index.html, it doesnt work at all. However, I am still running into issues after requiring it in the js file. How can I fix this?

Second question:
Why dont I get the Uncaught Error: jquery-confirm requires jQuery error if I import my js file using 'require' instead of  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of javascript context in Node Webkit. We must ensure all the javascript required inside the browser (the window context) is brought into that context by using the `src` attribute of a script tag.

Node Webkit places JavaScript from `require()` statements in the nodejs global context - and makes it unavailable inside the browser.

So we see errors such as `$ is not defined` or `$(...).button() is not a function` if files are in opposite contexts.

Comment: didn't see it the first time. `$(...).button` is not a function -- of jQuery. The button method is a method of jQueryUI not jQuery.

Comment: but it is working without problems when I use electron and import jquery in the html instead of the js file

Comment: Well that takes us back to square one then.  If I recall correctly, use of `require()` in the `index.html`  file will put the included script into the node context. So you should be using the `<script src="...">` form to get the script into the `window` context.

Comment: when I do that, jquery is somehow undefined. I checked the jquery-confirm library and it is giving that error when jquery is undefined

Comment: You'll need to put all of the `window` context JS files in `src` attributes. Not just jQuery. Did you put `jquery-confim` in `<script src="...">` too?

Comment: I put all of them in src attirbutes. Now I am getting 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapToggle is not a function' for the bootstrap toggle library

Comment: Good! That's progress. So you'll also need to put a script tag with src in for the bootstrap toggle library too. There is a pattern developing. It's only a matter of a few edits now :-)

Comment: I already had a script tag for that but I fixed it by putting my code in 
'window.onload = function(){' . My code worked without problems in electron but I think that is because electron waits for everything to load before executing your javascript file, however, I needed window.onload for nw.js

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it sorted.